# I cannot add second app!

Tags: support, stackapps

I added the Stack alert app for chrome from the apps section, but when I wanted to add the plugin for firefox  I didn't had any other link where I could download it from, the apps section changed to this:

[image]

First the plugins link was listed there, in the apps section, together with stackprinter link.
[image]

Shouldn't be a suggestion page add more apps in this section ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links to the example applications are only shown when you have not yet authorized any application, just to make you understand which genre of applications the page is referring.
After you authorize an application, those links are not shown anymore.

Those links are all for questions on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com), though.

- [Stack Alert [Google Chrome Extension] - Keep tabs on your inbox without needing to have a Stack Exchange site open.](https://stackapps.com/questions/2874/stack-alert-google-chrome-extension-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing)
- [SENotifier, a Stack Exchange inbox notifier for Mac OS X](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x)
- [StackPrinter: The Stack Exchange Printer Suite](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite)

If you need another application, you can just search it on Stack Apps.

Comment: yes but firefox plugin was first under this section and now I cannot find it here

Comment: Just execute it, and it will request you the authorization. If it doesn't do it, then remove it, and reinstall it.

Comment: I didn't downloaded it I first installed chrome plugin from that apps section and then I wanted to return to get the firefox plugin and I got this

Comment: The page you are watching just lists the applications you authorized; it's not a list of applications you can install.

Comment: I see that but first time it was, do you know from where I can get the  .xpi file

Comment: found it at mozzilla https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stackoverflow-bar/ there are four plugins there hope is the right one

Comment: the plugins link was listed there in the apps section, together with stackprinter,

Comment: The link is showed there, until you don't remove it. After it is removed, the link is not shown anymore, and you cannot re-add it from that page.

Comment: I edited the post added an image

Comment: this was: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-alert/ I was under the impression, because that Stack alert is a default app suggestion. now I saw with a different user it isn't

Comment: @Eduard There are four apps suggested on that tab (only if you have no apps), three are chosen at random to display.  They're effectively ads for apps we think are neat.